# How to let my bot auto connect to voice channel in every server after start up?

Tags: java, discord-jda

How to let my bot automatically joins a voice channel in every server by giving the voice channel id in the json file in JAVA, Discord-JDA

```
{
    "512176335825928204": {
        "voice_channel_id": "867720908658704385"
    },
    "731884435523371008": {
        "voice_channel_id": "900379684536209409"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the onReady event to check when the bot goes online. Then you want to iterate through the guilds.

Code for joining a voice channel:

```
Guild#getAudioManager().openAudioConnection(voiceChannel);
```